# Upgrading from Jetty 8 to Jetty 9

Tags: jsp, jetty

We have migrated from jetty 8 to jetty 9 and we have encountered multiple error on jsp pages that are working in jetty 8 like JSP Error : contains invalid expression,failed to parse exception. Also some of our other pages are not found because of doubling of slash on the url path. They are perfectly working on Jetty 8 but not on Jetty 9. Are there any list that will provide guidelines what to check when migrating from Jetty 8 to Jetty 9 version? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Jetty 8 to Jetty 9 is many major versions of upgrade.

> Reminder: Jetty versioning (since 1995) has been ...
>
> `<servlet_support>.<major_version>.<minor_version>`

That means, from Jetty 8.1.x to 9.4.x you have 5 major version releases of Jetty (that's a *big* jump in versions)

Some things of note:

- JSP Engine moved from buggy Glassfish JSP Engine to Apache Jasper JSP.
- Servlet spec changed path normalization rules/behaviors (internal normalization is allowed, but only to determine the specific webapp to dispatch to, normalization in all other scopes is not permitted)
- HTTP Spec support moved from RFC2616 (obsolete) to RFC7230 (and others)
- Cookie Spec support updated to support RFC6265 to meet current browser minimum requirements (Version 1 cookies no longer supported)
- HTTP/0.9 support dropped (and all associated behaviors in parser/generator)
- HTTP/2 support added
- Lenient UrlEncoded parsing behavior of forms dropped.  Bad form encoding will trigger an error 400 now. (This was a security and data corruption related change)

The warnings / errors in your JSPs are likely from buggy (non-spec compliant) JSPs usage, or that your JSPs relied on buggy behavior present in Glassfish JSP Engine.

The double-slash in a URI/URL has meaning to the servlet spec and many libraries.  This is not filtered out during dispatching (request/include/forward/error/async) to a Servlet/Filter Chain.  The normalization does occur, internally, but is only used to identify the appropriate Context Path (a specific webapp) to dispatch the request to.

As long as you use the Servlet and JSP specs properly, you should have no issues upgrading from Jetty 8.x.x to Jetty 9.x.x (millions of jetty websites have done this without issue)